# How to stretch body background image in css property depends on contents

Tags: html, css

I am having a html page with body background image. And inside body there is a `<div>` and inside that a horizontal tab.
Tab1 and Tab2 content lengths are different. So depends on the content i have to increase and decrease the body background image.

Thanking you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Stretched Background</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Remove margins from the 'html' and 'body' tags, and ensure the page takes up full screen height */
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
/* Set the position and dimensions of the background image. */
#page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
/* Specify the position and layering for the content that needs to appear in front of the background image. Must have a higher z-index value than the background image. Also add some padding to compensate for removing the margin from the 'html' and 'body' tags. */
#content {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px;}
</style>
<!-- The above code doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6. To address this, we use a conditional comment to specify an alternative style sheet for IE 6 -->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y:hidden;}
body {overflow-y:auto;}
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
#content {position:static;padding:10px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-background"><img src="http://www.htmlcodes.me/images/backgrounds/background-image-3.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Fireworks"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <h2>Stretched Background Example</h2>
    <p>The background image here has been acheived using an HTML/CSS hack. The page is layered. The image uses the HTML <code>img</code> tag - not the CSS <code>background-image</code> property.</p>
    <p>This text appears in front of the background image. This is because we've used CSS to layer the content in front of the background image. The background image will stretch to fit your browser window. You can see the image grow and shrink as you resize your browser.</p>
    <p>Go ahead - resize your browser!</p>
        <p>Back to the <a href="http://www.htmlcodes.me/backgrounds/stretch-background-image.cfm">stretch background tutorial</a>.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or u can try this link

```
http://www.htmlcodes.me/backgrounds/stretch-background-image.cfm
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could use the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size) property, [very few browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size).

If it is a small image (something like a texture) you should use [`background-repeat`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#properties2). If not, perhaps use an image large enough to cover your entire div without requiring stretching.

Optionally, look into using a HTML/CSS hack as detailed by prash.

Comment: hi,
I don't want to repeat the image. I want to increase the size of that image depends on content.

Answer (score 0):

U can use repeat property..`background-image:repeat:`
otherwise
i think u can use

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Comment: I am asking about the height and you mention here about the width.

Comment: But you were mentioned this height and width already. Problem is that if the content is increasing i have to increase the height of the background image.
But in the above case(your code), background image is fixed. while scrolling contents only moving.